# Combinations - no repetition for mirrors?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My question is, if there is a simple explanation as to why mirrors aren't counted twice with binomials such as it is in the case it's not a mirror?

Here is an **example**:

Consider the elements {1, 4}. How many different ways can these be added? Clearly the answer is 3:

1 + 4

4 + 4

1 + 1

The answer is not as clear with larger lists though, and I'm having trouble understanding why

Calculating the amount of choices with binomials, I get 2 choices for the first value, 2 choices for the second value, and divide by 2 to avoid double counting:

[image]

Clearly it gives the wrong answer. **So now to my real question:
Why is not 4 + 4(mirror objects) counted twice, but 1 + 4(non mirror objects) is? is there a simple explanation to this?**

Comment: Are you asking why $1+4$ could be seen as distinct from $4+1$ but $4+4$ is seen as the same as $4+4$?

Comment: I guess that's essentially what I'm asking yeah, it makes sense that 1 + 4 and 4 + 1 could be seen as distinct. For some reason it just seemed a bit odd to me, but I guess I've got some flawed thinking going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to get a $4 + 4$. You must select a $4$ on the first character and $4$ on the second character.

With the $1 + 4$ case, we select a $1$ as the first term and a $4$ on the second term. This is equivalent to selecting a $4$ on the first term and a $1$ on the second term. So there are two distinct permutations $(1, 4), (4, 1)$. We want to denote equivalence. From an algebra standpoint, we are "dividing out" by the Symmetry group $S_{2}$, which is the group of permutations on two elements. Doing this says that $(1, 4) \equiv (4, 1)$. Note that $S_{2}$ has $2! = 2$ elements, so that is why you divide out the quantity by $2$.

Another way to look at this is by enumerating the elements: 
$(1, 1)$ 
$(1, 4)$ 
$(4, 1)$ 
$(4, 4)$

So start with $(1, 1)$. When you permute the elements of this tuple, you just get $(1, 1)$ back. The same logic applies to $(4, 4)$. This is why $4 + 4$ and $1 + 1$ are the same.

When you deal with $(1, 4)$ and permute it, you get $(4, 1)$ back.

So if we partition the enumerations where two tuples are equivalent by the same sum, then we have the partitions: 
$(1, 1)$ 
$(4, 4)$ 
$(1, 4) = (4, 1)$

Notice three partitions, hence your count.

Comment: Thank you for good and quick response, makes perfect sense and I feel like it fixed some stupid way I had of looking at the problem.

Comment: Glad to help! Algebra and graph theory are always nice to haves with combinatorics. They are closely related fields. :-)